# Check if st_intesection is true/false Sf package

Tags: r, r-sf

How do I check if point intersect with polygon with boolean results, using sf package in R

```
library(sf)
dub<- st_as_sf(data.frame(lon=72.917,lat=19.112), coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)
a<- st_as_sf(data.frame(lon=72.930,lat=19.112), coords=c("lon","lat"), crs=4326)
buf<- st_buffer(a,0.01)
```

I tried length of intersection but it doesn't work

```
length(st_intersection(dub,buf))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `st_intersects` not `st_intersection` and set sparse = FALSE

```
> st_intersects(dub, buf, sparse = FALSE) 
# although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes 
# that they are planar
#       [,1]
# [1,] FALSE
```

Comment: @ sebdalgarno I get False for both points (Inside and outside polygon)  `PointIN<- st_as_sf(data.frame(lon=72.930,lat=19.112), coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)
Pointout<- st_as_sf(data.frame(lon=72.8702,lat=19.112), coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)
a<- st_as_sf(data.frame(lon=72.930,lat=19.112), coords=c("lon","lat"), crs=4326)
buf<- st_buffer(a,0.05) 

st_intersects(PointIN, buf) %>% length > 1
st_intersects(Pointout, buf) %>% length > 1`

Comment: my apologies - see revised answer

Comment: I too came across spare arguments. Anyhow thanks for pointing out st_intersect :)